# Drag and drop from table to the same table

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, drag-and-drop

I have a page looks so:

[image]

These tables are the same table is called: Tasks.

In the first one, I show the records that `Done = False`.

In the second one, I show the records that `Done = True`.

I want to drag and drop tasks from the lower table to the upper table (and when I drop it in the upper table, I want to change the Done from True to False).

Can someone know about a tutorial how can I do it?

Any help appreciated!

Comment: did you try searching yourself? Likely any answers wil come from readers of post using google for you

Comment: I tried and found from table to another:
http://jqueryui.com/sortable/#connect-lists

Comment: why won't that work ? Does what you want

Comment: because it is only visual. by this way, I won't be able to change the value of 'Done'.

Comment: use `drop` event to manage data change. Read the API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using JqueryUI sortable.  There are some good events that you can tie into for when items are dragged between lists.  [Receive](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#event-receive) will probably be the one most relevant to you.  So working from the example you cited i made this [JSFiddle to demo](http://jsfiddle.net/VeWWv/7/):

```
$(function() {
  $( "#sortable1, #sortable2" ).sortable({
    connectWith: ".connectedSortable",
    receive: function( event, ui ) {

        //This function is called whenever you drag between 
        //your javascript here to update your property.
        alert("foo");
    }                               
  }).disableSelection();
});
```